# Android login via Xing

Tags: android, authentication, xing

I am trying to make my application login via facebook and xing.
It was able to to do it with Facebook API but not with xing.

Any idea how can I do this with xing api? 
https://dev.xing.com/plugins/login_with

xing API provide a plugin for web developers, but not a jar for android developer!

Comment: If `xing` dont give SDK for android maybe you can't do it on native code, but you can using a webview to do login only when xing button it's clicked on you android app, you only need to do a login on web and get data from webview, it's a solution if you can't find another one

Comment: try this link Integration ZXing library directly into my Android application

Comment: I need to implement xing not zxing :)

Answer (score 0):

Xing recently released an [ADK/API client](https://github.com/xing/xing-android-sdk) that provides login on android functionality and implements the requests for you. It's currently provided as an alpha, but you can give it a try.